# Why is movement the consequence of a force and not the other way around?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces

I know this question might seem a bit ambiguous, but hear me out.

Suppose we have a table on which we exert a certain force $\vec{F}$. If $\vec{F}$ has a big enough magnitude, and is set in the right direction, the table will start to move. Let's suppose that the table is moving at constant velocity.

Conversely, if we consider that we are *imposing* a constant velocity $\vec{v}$ on one end of the table, a reactive force will be created.

It always seems to me, in textbooks and in lectures, that force is the cause of movement and not the other way around. Is this completely true? Or have I just stumbled upon some linguistic quirk that lead to a fallacy?

My knowledge of certain (fundamental) abstractions in pure physics is a bit limited, so I'd like to know the answer, in as much detail as possible. Keep in mind that I'm not asking for equations like Newton's second law, or for some mathematical derivation per se. I would like to understand both formally and intuitively why one phenomena causes the other.

Comment: Just think of a freely moving body in a empty space. V is constant. But not force is required, active or reactive there is no one. Does this solve your doubt?

Comment: In the Newtonian model, force is the cause of momentum change. How do you *impose* a velocity? Are you building a new dynamic/kinematic system?

Comment: Would it be helpful to consider this in terms of balance, in that the force invariably arises from an imbalance in a system, which is otherwise in equilibrium, because this will minimise potential energy. So, if I follow you correctly, the floor will always react to you jumping on it, because it has achieved equilibrium, but you by jumping and falling, temporarily are out of balance. So force causes velocity. Am I making any headway, or sense : ), to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What, if anything, makes forces the "cause" and acceleration the "effect"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11478/)

Answer (score 2):

The question links constant speed with forces, but given Newton' second law, it's better to change the question a bit, and consider:

> why don't we say that *imposing* a constant **acceleration** causes a force?

This question [has been asked before here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11478/75633) and also at the [Philosophy SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/622/what-distinguishes-cause-from-effect-when-they-are-simultaneous), with more interesting answers, particularly [this one](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/4462), from which I reproduce an enlightening example:

> suppose that at some time t we have a big spherical mass M (event A), and from a distance r away you (mass m) experience a real force equal to GMm/r^2 (event B). In this case, A implies B by Newtonian gravity. However, B does not imply A: there could instead be a number of different masses that happen to produce that force.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the situation of two balls on a surface. Let us start with the initial state of a non-stationary $m_1$ rolling towards a stationary $m_2$ with some velocity $v$.

When $m_1$ approaches a minimum distance to $m_2$, the *fundamental* intermolecular forces between the two balls (on leading edges) ramp up dramatically. This will cause a acceleration in $m_1$ and $m_2$, propelling $m_2$ away from $m_1$ with a velocity determined by the elasticity of the collision.

In this case, you can see the change in both force and velocity. You might think that because initially there was only a velocity in the situation, and some at some point during there was a force, the force was caused by the velocity, but this is not the case.

It will be helpful to imagine (for simplicities sake) the situation as a stroboscopic one for this example (where all events occur in “flashes” of time). Let us now look at the collision of the two balls in this sense. First of all, the forces are not velocity dependant (just as you would not expect the gravitation effect on a satellite to be velocity dependant), but dependant on the relative position of the particles. Note that there is no “moment of collision” because the intermolecular forces are simply functions which increase in magnitude as separation decreases. You can see from this that at each flash of time, the forces between the particles of the two balls increase in each moment towards minimum separation, and decrease in each moment away from minimum separation. **The increase and decrease in force is caused by change in position, not velocity.**

Please realize that change in position and velocity are not the same thing, because the change in position is irrespective of time. It did not matter to the collision what the initial velocities were, only how close the two balls got to one another.

Answer (score 0):

It's true, the force causes the movement.
The movement implies change in the momentum, which by definition is force. 
If you move the table, it goes from $0$ to some velocity $v$, which means that you are changing the linear momentum.